# read only drive with no way of fixing or rebooting

Tags: filesystem

The hard drive is acting super corrupt. Any help is welcome... We dont have physical access to this computer. We can ssh and remotely solve this problem.

```
$ fsck -p -f  
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: recovering journal
fsck.ext4: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root


/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********


$ reboot

Failed to open /dev/initctl: No such device or address
Failed to talk to init daemon.


# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-38-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: I infer (from the `$` prompt) that you didn't do this as `root`, right. That could be a problem.

Comment: I have to be root, you cannot run fsck etc. with a user account, or reboot the machine.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this question is old, but it looks like the system was toast.  I just faced a similar situation with my Linux box at home.  I woke it up remotely from a long sleep (hibernate mode) using my insider raspberry pi.  Usually this works without error 99% of the time.

However, once in a long while there is some sort of file system corruption during the sleep.  This could be due to a bad memory address, or a SSD sector going faulty.  It refuses to reboot normally, so I forced it with:

`sudo reboot -f`

The first time asks nicely.  The second time will force it.  Not a nice solution, but it came back to life after that.  It's good to check the disk afterwards to check for broken struture.